# Jackson - Serialize boolean to 1/0 instead of true/false

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have REST resource that receives JSON object which is a map from user ID to some boolean that indicate if this user had errors.

Since I'm expecting a large number of users, I would like to shrink the size of this JSON by using 1/0 instead of true/false.

I tried and found that during desalinization Jackson will convert 1/0 to true/false successfully, but is there a way to tell Jackson (maybe using annotation?) to serialize this boolean field to 1/0 instead of true/false?

Comment: Add a [custom serializer](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomSerializers) for the `boolean` type.

Answer (score 20):

Since jackson-databind 2.9, `@JsonFormat` supports numeric (0/1) boolean serialization (but not deserialization):

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.NUMBER)
abstract boolean isActive();
```

See https://github.com/fasterxml/jackson-databind/issues/1480 which references this SO post.

Comment: @danieln: I suggest marking this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 17):

Here is a Jackson `JsonSerializer` that will serialize booleans as `1` or `0`.

```
public class NumericBooleanSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Boolean> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Boolean b, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
        jsonGenerator.writeNumber(b ? 1 : 0);
    }
}
```

Then annotate boolean fields like so:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = NumericBooleanSerializer.class)
private boolean fieldName;
```

Or register it in a Jackson `Module`:

```
module.addSerializer(new NumericBooleanSerializer());
```

Comment: Just in case of "Class serializer has no default (no arg) constructor", have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/54605694/573034